# Docker exit after entrypoint

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im trying to write a docker image for s3cmd. When I run the image built from the Dockerfile via docker-compose, the container exit before the command in docker compose run.

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY ./.s3cfg /s3cmd_repo/.s3cfg.example
COPY entrypoint.sh /s3cmd_repo/

RUN chmod +x /s3cmd_repo/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/s3cmd_repo/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "--- INITIALIZING SS# CONFIGURATIONS ---"
envsubst < /s3cmd_repo/.s3cfg.example > ~/.s3cfg
s3cmd ls
echo "=== END ==="
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'    
services:
  execution:
    image: s3
    command: s3cmd ls
```

I also tried using `tail -f /etc/issue`, the container did not exit, but the docker compose command could not run.

Comment: What happen when your run the image as a standalone image  (without docker-compose)?

Comment: the container will exit automatically

Comment: can you add the `docker log YOUR_CONTAINER_ID` output? it will help.

Comment: i cant make the container to stay up, it exits immediately right after it starts

Comment: I'll note that this is a class of tool (a short-lived process whose principal goal is interacting with the host filesystem) that's not a good fit for Docker in general; you'll have more success long-term just installing it on your host system.

Comment: I would like to upload some files to S3 in my CI/CD, so i was thinking of creating a s3cmd container to automate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I run the image built from the Dockerfile via docker-compose, the
>   container exit before the command in docker compose run.

That is expected. That command in the docker compose file : `s3cmd ls` is appended to the entrypoint of your s3' Dockerfile.
So something like that is executed :

```
/s3cmd_repo/entrypoint.sh s3cmd ls
```

the two args are just ignored during the sh script execution.

To execute multiple commands to start a container, you don't need to define an ENTRYPOINT. Instead specify the commands to run in the docker-compose file :

```
version: '3'    
services:
  execution:
    image: s3
    command: sh -c "/s3cmd_repo/entrypoint.sh && s3cmd ls"
```

Note that `sh` works in any Linux distrib, `bash` doesn't (Alpine for example).

Comment: but what if i want to execute ```/s3cmd_repo/entrypoint.sh``` automatically every time the container starts? because the reason of using ```ENTRYPOINT``` to to avoid  manually running it.

Comment: The reason of using ENTRYPOINT is defining the default executed program. Docker is not natively designed to consider multiple programs to run. The standard way is using a command to pass it to the entrypoint as you did but since your script ignore the args. That is helpless.  Since `command` overrides the CMD in the Dockerfile you can still replace `ENTRYPOINT ["/s3cmd_repo/entrypoint.sh"]` by `CMD["/s3cmd_repo/entrypoint.sh"]`. That will allow a default behavior but in any case you have to override the command arg if you want to define multiple programs to run.

Comment: The other important detail here is that the `ENTRYPOINT` runs to completion (taking the `CMD` as arguments, as shown) and then the container exits.  If you want to run the command you're passing in the `ENTRYPOINT` script needs to do it itself; frequently with `exec "$@"` as the last line in the script.

Comment: Just my opinion : that is the way which Docker is designed, you may find it not perfect (and it occurs me very often) but you should not try to twist the standard way of using Docker without important reasons.

Comment: thanks for the clarifications, before this i thought entry point was a command to run at the startup of the container and continue receive new commands.